# Writing an app web browser to access ip address

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ip-address

I am trying to write a simple app in xcode for my iphone to access an ip address. I followed several different tutorials and have created a simple browser that allows me to access google or yahoo. However I would like to access an ip address.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Do you mean to be able to FTP files to the IP address? Or for just browsing? Like: http://74.125.224.72/

Comment: just for browsing. I would like to be able to simply view an IP address like 64.125.224.72

Comment: See the below answer, it should work a treat for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some.ip.adress.here"];
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];
```

Comment: the URLWithStrin:@"some.ip.adress.here"]; does the string command handle the numbers in the ip address or will it only take a http://www.adress.com type url?